# React, Fetch sending empty body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So I have a problem about sending a request. Body is not empty at all since I can log it. But somehow when I make a request, the body is empty. It was weird so I copied a working request code that didn't send an empty body, guess what? Body empty. I have cors enabled.

empty body === second

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vFw7.png)

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      let data = new FormData()
      data.set("key", "")
      data.append("image", groupPFP.file)

      const res = await fetch("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      })

      const parseRes = await res.json()

      if (parseRes.status === 200) {
        const imgbbLink = parseRes.data.display_url

        const resData = { groupProfileImage: imgbbLink, groupName, groupAbout }

        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/group/create", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            JwtToken: localStorage.getItem("JwtToken"),
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(resData),
        })

        const parseResPFP = await res.json()

        if (parseResPFP.status === 429) {
          return toast.error("Too Many Requests, try again later")
        }

        toast.success("Group created successfully")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

No errors

Comment: is it the first or second request that has an empty body?

Comment: secound........

Comment: How are you determining that it is empty? Are you looking in the browser's developer tools Network tab? Or are you attempting to parse it on the server and then looking at the post-parsing result?

Comment: I get 204 No Content in network and console

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204 What are your expecting it to send?

Comment: _"204 No Content"_ means the **response** has no content. It still indicates a successful request

Comment: Does the response JSON really include a `status` property? I would have though you'd check [`res.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) instead of `parseRes.status`. Same for your second response

Comment: Tried all yall said not working

Comment: not working how, exactly? What response did you expect back, instead of the 204? And you still haven't clarified whether you've actually checked whether your _request_ actually has an empty body or not - did you look at your request in your network tool to see what it's _sending_ (not what it's receiving)?

Comment: The 204 response is for your [CORS pre-flight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) which is typical. As far as I can see, there is no problem at all

Comment: IT IS SENDING NOTHING. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vFw7.png. It needs to send { groupProfileImage: imgbbLink, groupName, groupAbout }, i can log this data but it stops at fetch request.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show anything about what it is or isn't sending, it just shows some URLs. look in your browser's Network tool, click on the request, expand it, look at the request body. The code you've shown makes it look like it should send a JSON object (even if the properties within it may or may not be empty).

Comment: `it stops`...you mean your JS crashes, or what? Please try to be more specific and less vague about the behaviour of the code. Then it'll be a lot easier for us to understand and help. The screenshot does seem to show there's no response from the last POST (which is the one for the API). Have you checked the browser's Console for JS errors or anything?

Comment: Also...have you debugged this on the server-side, to see what's actually being received by the API (if anything)?